# Compiler Error: Invalid value in assignment when trying to change the origin of a UISwitch

Tags: iphone

The following piece of code is giving me a compiler error: Invalid value in assignment, while changing the origin.

`CGPoint switchOrigin = CGPointMake(currentOrigin.x, currentOrigin.y + kTweenMargin);
UISwitch *choiceSwitch = [UISwitch alloc];
**choiceSwitch.frame.origin = switchOrigin;**`

But when I change it to the following it works properly.

`CGPoint switchOrigin = CGPointMake(currentOrigin.x, currentOrigin.y + kTweenMargin);
UISwitch *choiceSwitch = [UISwitch alloc];
**CGRect switchFrame = choiceSwitch.frame;
switchFrame.origin = switchOrigin;**`

Can any one explain me the logic behind this.

Thanks and Regards,
Pranathi

Answer (score 1):

You want to init your instances.